# ArgumentError (comparison of Hash with Hash failed) - Filtering array results by matching has values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Here are samples of my arrays:**

**Array #1:**

```
todays_listings_clean = 
{:id=>"48442", :address=>"5489 Milburough Line", :locality=>"Burlington", :neighbourhood=>"Rural Burlington", :lot_front=>147.0, :lot_depth=>665.0, :property_type=>"Detached", :asking_price=>2888000} 

{:id=>"48446", :address=>"275 St Leonard's Ave", :locality=>"Toronto", :neighbourhood=>"Lawrence Park", :lot_front=>15.0, :lot_depth=>45.0, :property_type=>"Detached", :asking_price=>3395000}
```

**Array #2:**

```
past_listings_clean = 
{:address=>"36 Beachgrove Cres", :locality=>"Whitby", :neighbourhood=>"Taunton North", :lot_front=>3.0, :lot_depth=>9.0, :property_type=>"Detached", :closed_price=>344000, :sold_date=>#<Date: 2013-03-05 ((2456357j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>}

{:address=>"4 Irene Cres", :locality=>"Brampton", :neighbourhood=>"Fletcher''s Meadow", :lot_front=>9.0, :lot_depth=>29.0, :property_type=>"Detached", :closed_price=>394900, :sold_date=>#<Date: 2013-03-04 ((2456356j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>}
```

I am trying to run the following logic and am getting `ArgumentError (comparison of Hash with Hash failed)` :

```
todays_listings_clean.each do |tl|

  past_listings_clean.select do |pl|
  
      (pl[:locality] == tl[:locality]) &&
      (pl[:neighbourhood] == tl[:neighbourhood]) &&
      !(pl[:closed_price]).nil?
  end
end
```

Any thoughts on why this issue is occurring and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: From what you have shown, neither of these "arrays" are actually arrays ... they are hashes

Comment: Besides the fact your "arrays" are actually hashes, there is one more problem: even if `todays_listings_clean` and `past_listings_clean` _are_ arrays, the code you posted doesn't do anything useful: the external `each` will return just the original enumerable and internal one has no side effects... So the code just heats the atmosphere at the moment. So, 2 questions: are you sure your arrays are arrays (and how do they look like in this case) and what result do you expect from your code?